# Struts 2 - Accessing different properties on the ValueStack sharing the same name

Tags: struts2, ognl, valuestack

Struts 2 will resolve all property names during view rendering against the top object in the ValueStack first. But how can one access a property with the same name on the object lower on the stack?

Example:

Let's say I have an Action class called MyAction and it has a a logDate property. In the view rendered after this action is invoked, there's this:

```
<s:iterator value="users" status="itStatus">
  <s:property value="logDate"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Now imagine a User object also has a logDate property. During the iteration, Struts 2 will always push the current user object to the top of the ValueStack effectively resolving all property names against it. But, what if I wanted to access logDate from the action? What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an index to look at a substack. For example:
[0].logDate would start the search at the stop of the stack and find the logDate on the user object. [1].logDate would start the search one level deeper and find the logDate on the Action class. This [OGNL page](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/ognl-basics.html) (see the section right above the Accessing static properties header) has some more detail and here is another [explanation](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/value-stack-internals.html).

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much for this quick answer :)

P.S.
Is there any way to mark the question as answered?

Comment: You are quite welcome - glad it helped. There should be a hollow check mark listed next to the answer. Clicking it will turn it to green to accept it.